# How to convert 2d into row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a data-frame like:

```
          a                     b                  
 [[35.6113, -95.855]]    [[[36.028, -95.93], [36.10, -95.82] .... ]]]
```

How can i convert it into like this:

```
      a                     b                  
 [35.6113, -95.855]  [36.028, -95.93]
 [35.6113, -95.855]  [36.10,  -95.82]
  ....                      ....
  ....                      ....
```

I tried with `df['b'].apply(pd.Series)` but it's throwing error as it must be 1 d. Is there a simple process to do it?

Edit:

```
df['b'][0] 

array([[[ 36.0285042 , -95.938618  ],
       [ 36.108158  , -95.8241013 ],
       [ 36.1544989 , -95.9931978 ],
       [ 36.515477  , -96.139459  ],
       [ 36.1330019 , -95.8372588 ],
       [ 36.0405703 , -96.0028027 ],
       [ 35.850413  , -96.072558  ],
       [ 36.0814011 , -95.7677365 ],
       [ 36.40235964, -95.97271572],
       [ 36.0299891 , -95.7085335 ],
       [ 36.328715  , -95.488263  ],
       [ 36.781739  , -95.99514   ],
       [ 36.05102591, -95.72716157],
       [ 35.866565  , -95.523982  ],
       [ 35.8321172 , -96.049276  ],
       [ 35.9691288 , -95.8382827 ],
       [ 36.0872146 , -96.1264932 ],
       [ 35.9682564 , -96.1106048 ],
       [ 36.1375913 , -95.8341317 ],
       [ 35.7914036 , -95.8728959 ]]])
```

Comment: You want to forward fill missing values ?

Comment: there are no  missing values.  It's just a long array in b.I simply want to transpose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'a':df.a.repeat(df.b.str.len()),'b':sum(df.b.tolist(),[])})
s.apply(lambda x : x.str[0])

Out[104]: 
                    a                   b
0  [35.6113, -95.855]  [35.6113, -95.855]
0  [35.6113, -95.855]  [35.6113, -95.855]
```

Comment: yes, I have to split it...
 I am getting error as ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (1,20,2) .I edited the question with some more info

Comment: Don't think this is the right dupe though. Looks like you're repeating the rows here rather than splittin ginto new rows

Comment: @yatu that is just my test data ,I just create the b have two same list of list .

Comment: In any case OP does have several other columns in this case to also repeat, and does not seem to figure it out using the dupe, hope you don't mind me reopening @wen

Comment: @yatu which one you mentioned .?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955200/python-how-to-unpack-a-list-of-list-of-tuples-in-a-dataframe/56955846#56955200 @wen

Comment: `sum(df.b.tolist(),[])` is neat here btw :)

Comment: @yatu yes, if you think that is not the dup feel free to open it :-)

Comment: Actually your answer is pretty neat, I'm starting to think it is a dupe..... haha I overcomplicated mine

Answer (score 0):

If using tuple doesn't limit you, you can solve this with:

```
s = pd.Series([tuple(x) for x in a])
```